# Can I change the bootloader image on my unlocked moto g in an easy way for another custom image?

Tags: motorola-moto-g, bootloader, customization

I have unlocked the bootloader of my moto G 2013 mobile and now I get the warning message and I'd like to change it for a simple highresolution image of my choice.

Is there a really simple way to do it? I am not too tech-savvy. :)[image]

Comment: There's pretty much nothing to do with the bootloader that's 'simple', and if you're not careful when changing things to do with the bootloader you could brick your phone. Changing the bootloader image (not the animation) is very difficult, because the image is part of the bootloader, which is (probably) not open-source.

Comment: @JoshHolland Ok. Perfect. I wont touch it then. Cheers.